Bernoulli factory for $p(1-p)$
Consider an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli variables $X_i$ with unknown parameter $p \in (0,1)$. That is $X_i$ takes the value $1$ with probability $p$, and $0$ with probability $1-p$. Using a possibly random number $n$ of these variables as inputs, I want to produce a Bernoulli variable $Y$ with parameter $p(1-p)$. Note that this is a particular case of a Bernoulli factory. My target is to achieve $\mathrm E[n]$ as small as possible.

An obvious approach is to observe $n=2$ inputs and generate the output $Y$ as $X_1(1-X_2)$.

This can be refined by "short-circuiting" the product: (i) if $X_1 = 0$ it is not necessary to observe $X_2$ (the result will be $0$ anyway). This gives $\mathrm E[n] = 1+p$. Alternatively, (ii) if $X_2$ is observed first, and $X_1$ is observed only when needed, $\mathrm E[n] = 2-p$.

If one of the two approaches 2.(i) and 2.(ii) is selected with equal probability, $\mathrm E[n] = 3/2$ independent of $p$.

If the process is going to be repeated to produce many independent outputs, from the observed inputs it is possible to have a good guess whether $p \leq 1/2$ or not, and based on this choose 2.(i) or 2.(ii) respectively. This would give $\mathrm E[n] \approx 1+\min\{p, 1-p\}$ in the long term.


I don't see how to reduce $\mathrm E[n]$ further.
On the other hand, both from entropy considerations (the entropy of $Y$ is smaller than that of $X_i$; see A below) or from the Cramér-Rao bound (see B for details), it seems that it might be possible to achieve a smaller $\mathrm E[n]$, even less than $1$ (but then I'm not sure if those bounds take into account the fact that $p$ is unknown).
Is there any method that achieves $\mathrm E[n]$ smaller than the ones I have described?

A. Entropy of $X_i$ and of $Y$

B. Argument based on the Cramér-Rao bound
The output $Y$ can be considered an unbiased estimator of $p(1-p)$. Therefore, the Cramér-Rao bound (for $n$ fixed) or Wolfowitz's extension to the sequential case (for random $n$) [Wolfowitz, 1947] can be applied. The latter is expressed as
$$
\mathrm{Var}[Y] \geq \frac{\left(\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d \mathrm E[Y]}{\mathrm d p} \right)^2} {\mathrm E[n] \, \mathrm E \left[ \left(\displaystyle \frac{\partial f(x, p)} {\partial p} \right)^2 \right], }
$$
where $f(x, p)$ is the Bernoulli probability function with parameter $p$:
$$
f(x, p) = \begin{cases}
p & \text{for } x=1 \\
1-p & \text{for } x=0.
\end{cases} 
$$
Taking into account that $\mathrm E[Y] = p(1-p)$ and that $\mathrm{Var}[Y] = p(1-p)(1-p(1-p))$, this gives
$$
p(1-p)(1-p(1-p)) \geq \frac{(1-2p)^2}{\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm E [n]}{p(1-p)}},
$$
that is,
$$
\mathrm E [n] \geq \frac{(1-2p)^2}{1-p(1-p)}.
$$
The right-hand side of this inequality is less than $1$. Although this value is not necessarily achievable, it suggests that values of $\mathrm E [n]$ smaller than $1$ could be possible.
Reference
J. Wolfowitz, The efficiency of sequential estimates and Wald’s equation for sequential processes, Annals of Mathematical Statistics 18 (2) (1947) 215–230.

Your comment about the possibility that $E[n]$ could be "even less than $1$" implies you don't require the outputs to be independent.  Is that really the case?

@whuber Outputs should be independent. Edited, thanks

Could you share with us your insight as to how $E[n]$ could possibly be less than $1$ in that case?

@whuber Done. Sorry that it took some time

You may be aware of this already, but your question may be a special case of an open question in Nacu & Peres (2005), "Fast simulation of new coins from old".

@PeterO. Thanks. I didn't remember that. I'm assuing you mean their Question 2

This may not be an answer, or solution, but an idea of how you may be able to have $E[n] < 1+\min\{p, 1-p\}$, or rather $E[\frac n m]< 1+\min\{p, 1-p\}$, where $m$ is the number of Y outputs generated.
The basis of the idea is that we know that $p(1-p)<.25$, for any $p$. Beyond that, as we keep drawing values from $X$, we can determine an upper bound for $p$ (or lower bound if $p>.5$), and thus we can lower the bound from $.25$ to a smaller value.
So start by drawing the first value from $X$; if it is 1, you can immediately generate 4 values for $Y$ (all being 0's) w/o drawing any value from $X$. If instead it is 0, you know that $y=0$, and keep drawing from $X$ until you get a 1. If this value is compatible with $p(1-p)<.25$ you keep drawing.
But now you check the upper bound of the CI of $p$ (based on how long it took to get a 1). It eventually will be <.5 (or >.5 if you got many 1's), so you can now choose the right formula (either $X_1(1-X_2)$ or $(1-X_1)X_2$ to minimize how often you need a second draw from $X$. And you continue.
This process should allow you to sometimes generate values (all 0's) for $Y$ w/o drawing any value from $X$.
Now I am not sure if it gets us to $E(\frac n m)<1$, but it certainly gets us to $E[\frac n m]< 1+\min\{p, 1-p\}$, because, in the long run, a 1 will occur "too early", about $\frac p 2$ times, so we get to generate a number of 0's for $Y$ "for free" (w/o any draw from $X$).
Note that it should be possible to also generate 1's "for free"; we can get a low bound for $p$ (or $(1-p)$), and thus generate 1's when a 1 is "too late", which would further help.
Maybe a simulation would get us an idea of how this approach works.

So start by drawing the first value from X
; if it is 1, you can immediately generate 4 values for Y
(all being 0's) If I understand correctly, that violates the requirement of independent outputs, doesn't it?

How do you obtain any bounds on $p$ by means of observing only a finite number of draws from $X$??

Yes indeed, this does not give you independent Y's. But it would seem that the only way to get E[n]<1 is to predict a Y value w/o any draw from X; and that violates independence (because it is deterministic). Which is also what @whuber questions.
